# Tool to insert Unicode character by its numeric code

Tags: windows, keyboard-listener, unicode

Yet before Windows came, as a DOS user you maybe remember shortcuts like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+(numpad<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>4</kbd>) you could type anywhere to insert `@` (character #64).

I'm seeking for a Windows tool which can

1. **Convert typed hexadecimal (or decimal) number to appropriate Unicode character**
   Microsoft Word already has  sort of this functionality: you type `0A88`, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and `0A88` gets replaced by `ઈ`.
2. **Type** Unicode character selected in pop-up window **right into text**.

Both features should work **regardless of active application**, like universal tool sitting on the background.

I already know and use fantastic [BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html) character map but this one fulfills only requirement #2 (and only partially). In many cases I would also need a **tool offering feature #1** – while #2 is good-to-have in the same tool, but not mandatory (BabelMap can still be of use).

Comment: I can't find a script to do it, but I poked around AutoHotKey a bit, and it's capable of dealing with Unicode text. I suspect that you could write an AutoHotKey script that cut the current selection, turn it into a unicode character, and then paste it back down (or perhaps grab the input directly and type the unicode character in).

Comment: @MichaelKohne – I'm a big fan of AutoHotKey. I haven't seen nor wrote a solution so far. Still waiting if someone can come up with something interesting here.

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/47420/insert-unicode-characters-via-the-keyboard

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/13086/how-do-you-type-unicode-characters-using-hexadecimal-codes/

Comment: @Oxinabox – why not to create an answer instead of comments? :)

Comment: @miroxlav: I am not an expert on the tools used in those posts (i've never used them, beyond mauy years ago insterting nonstandard ascii characters with the numpad), and I also am not certain that they talk of the exact same thing you are. But they are of interest and relevance to anyone looking at this question later.